# Scapy route6 empty

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ipv6

I'm using scapy to build some IPv6 packets. I'm having trouble in the communications between hosts on the same network and with external links as well, I'm only able to communicate with my router. 
For example if I make a router solicitation request it works fine, but if I make a ICMPv6EchoRequest to the ff02::1(all nodes on the network) I only get an answer from the router and not the other connected hosts. 
If I use the ping6 command I can perfectly ping all the hosts on my network and external links as well, which leads me to think that it is a problem with scapy.

My conf.iface6 is on the right interface, **but** my route6 is empty(my route from IPv4 is not) even if I add a new route6 conf.route6.add(myip6, gw ='router ipv6', dev='interface') my route6 continues to be empty.
My conf.route6.routes are not empty  and I think they are well configured. 
I really don't see where's the problem, plus everything is working fine with the OS(which is Linux) IPv6 configurations .

Comment: Do you have routable IPv6 addresses, or are you trying to configure routes for link-local IPv6 addresses, which are not routable?

Comment: I have indeed routable global IPv6 addresses in every connected device to the router ...